# Dynamic Variant Price while adding variant into the Shopify cart

Tags: shopify, shopify-app

I have Shopify Store, where customer can design/customise their product before buying it. and based on the design / customisation price of the selected variant may get varied. but I think Shopify does not facilitate to change variant price dynamically while adding into cart.

Is any solution there I might be missing ? Any help will be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

There are a few solutions none of which are great.

#### Quantity based

Make the product price $1 and based on the options increase the quantity in order to meet the required price. With a little code you can change the cart to look like it's a single product, but the checkout will not be OK.

#### Variant based

If the product will have only a few price changes you can create different variants and change the variants based on the selected options. For example 10 different variants for 10 different prices.

#### App based

You can use an App such as https://apps.shopify.com/product-options to create options that can modify the product price. ( this will add dummy products to the checkout as well )

Comment: yeah, currently I am creating dummy products and add to the cart for that design/customisation cost.  and in the variant based solution you have given : we can not add that much variant because there are thousands of option we are providing while customising the product. and each combination/ customisation may have its own price.

Comment: @BhargavKaklotara then there isn't a better solution that I can think of. There can be a more specific app for this but I haven't seen or used one to this point.

Comment: Assigning different price is possible when we are creating orders via API, we just need to pass price explicitly along with variant ID in line item. but this is not possible while creating cart. this is might be because cart can be edited multiple times and same product/variant with different prices can be added if this is possible. but this is genuine issue Shopify must have to do something for this.

Comment: @Bhargav Kaklotara they will need to create another layer of complexity in order to achieve this. Considering the speed they are doing features I don't see it coming too soon.

Comment: hello @drip just need your suggestion here. is this possible with storefront API ? if you know something about Store Front API.

Comment: @BhargavKaklotara the short answer is no. The long answer is it can be done via a custom App that can create a separate variant for each product and you buy that. But in order to manage this from the admin panel will be Hell so I don't recommend it. Another option is to ask in the Shopify forum for App recommendation for this if there is any. But using only the Storeftont API it won't be possible in any way without the use of predefined products/variants with set prices.

Comment: Many Thanks, let me stick with my current solution of adding another custom product to cart. really very thanks once again.

Answer (score 0):

For Plus, you can use shopify script to edit the line items directly.

If you're not Plus users, you have to do it on server-side, i.e. your backend

1. submit an ajax request on your custom product page
2. backend receives the request. Use admin API to create a new product variant on the fly
3. set the variant price, weight, quantity, or other properties based on your business rules
4. return response to client
5. client receives a successful response. use cart ajax to add the new variant to cart
6. let client continue checkout

Upon order is made, use webhook to update inventory or other information required. But there is a problem regarding variant limit. For each product, you can only add 100 variants.

So you need to create new products when the variant is used up for the product. Alternatively, you can delete the existing variants. But the variants in customer carts will be cleared.

I am doing something similar to what you're doing so I think our approach will be more or less the same. Basically, there are only 2 solutions, either create a new product or new discount dynamically. Both approaches create many dummy/garbage data